# Derivative of Kronecker product of vector with itself

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vectors, matrix-calculus, kronecker-product

I'm struggling with the following problem. Suppose $\pmb{x}$ and $\pmb{y}$ are vectors of the same length and $\pmb{y}$ is not a function of $\pmb{x}$. What is the following derivative?

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \pmb{x}} (\pmb{y} - \pmb{x}) \otimes (\pmb{y} - \pmb{x})
$$

My thought was to write use $\pmb{z} = \pmb{y} - \pmb{x}$ and $\pmb{f} = \pmb{z} \otimes \pmb{z}$ and derive first:

\begin{align}
d\pmb{f} &= ((d\pmb{z}) \otimes \pmb{z}) + (\pmb{z} \otimes (d\pmb{z})) \\
&= (\pmb{I} \otimes \pmb{z})d\pmb{z} + (\pmb{z} \otimes \pmb{I})d\pmb{z} \\
&= ((\pmb{I} \otimes \pmb{z}) + (\pmb{z} \otimes \pmb{I}))d\pmb{z} \\
\frac{\partial \pmb{f}}{\partial \pmb{z}} &= (\pmb{I} \otimes \pmb{z}) + (\pmb{z} \otimes \pmb{I})
\end{align}

and then obtain by chain rule:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \pmb{x}} (\pmb{y} - \pmb{x}) \otimes (\pmb{y} - \pmb{x}) = -\left( (\pmb{I} \otimes (\pmb{y} - \pmb{x})) + ((\pmb{y} - \pmb{x}) \otimes \pmb{I}) \right)
$$

Which seems sensble. However, this is part of a Hessian I am deriving, and it's corresponding transpose element I derived to be:

$$
-2\left(\pmb{I} \otimes (\pmb{y} - \pmb{x})\right)
$$

Which is very similar but not the same. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: This doesn't really call for the chain rule. Just substitute $(dz\longrightarrow -dx)$ into the differential expression, and that leads directly to the given gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's clear out some definitions first.

If $f:z \to f(x)$ is a matrix valued function and there is a function $D_f$ such that
$$
f(z+h) = f(z) + D_f(z,h) + o(\|h\|)
$$
Then $D_f$ is the **differential** of $f$. If there exists a matrix valued function $A(z)$ such that
$$ D_f(z,h) = A(z) h$$
Then $A(z)$ is the **derivative** of $f$.

(This is sometimes called the *first identification theorem*; see for instance [Magnus and Neudecker, 1999](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047198633X)).

In the case at hand, we have
$$f(z+h) = (z+h)\otimes (z+h) = \underbrace{z\otimes z}_{f(z)} + \underbrace{(h\otimes z) + (z\otimes h)}_{D_f(z,h)} + \underbrace{h\otimes h}_{o(\|h\|)}$$

So, by the definition $D_f(z,h) = (h\otimes z) + (z\otimes h)$ is the differential of $z\otimes z$. Now we can use the identification theorem to say that, since
$$ D_f(z,h) = \big[(I\otimes z) + (z \otimes I)\big]h = A(z) h$$
the matrix
$$ A(z) =  (I\otimes z) + (z \otimes I)$$
is the derivative of $z \otimes z$.

So in the case at hand, the same reasoning brings you to the correct derivative
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(y-x)\otimes (y-x) = \big(I\otimes(x-y)\big) + \big((x-y) \otimes I\big)$$
which is what you found.

Check the other half of the Hessian: there has to be something wrong there!

Comment: Thanks! The other half had a mistake indeed. I also didn't mention a duplication matrix I use to take the derivative to a half-vectorization (didn't think it would matter). I got for the other half $-2  \left(\left(\pmb{y} - \pmb{x} \right)^{\top} \otimes \pmb{I}\right) \pmb{D}$ and for this part $- \pmb{D}^{\top} \left(  (\pmb{I} \otimes (\pmb{y} - \pmb{x}))  + ((\pmb{y} - \pmb{x}) \otimes \pmb{I}) \right)$. For some reason, these turn out to be each-others transposes numerically. I don't really get how, magic I guess :) But it will be sufficient

Comment: I didn't understand something, if X and Y are vectors, how do you make the Kronecker product of a matrix with a vector and get a vector as a result?

Answer (score 3):

The gradient that you found is correct. I re-derive it here to make this answer self-contained...

First note that the Kronecker product of two vectors can be expanded in two ways:
$$a\otimes b = (I_a\otimes b)\,a = (a\otimes I_b)\,b$$ where $I_a$ is the identity matrix whose dimensions are compatible with the $a$ vector, while $I_b$ is compatible with the $b$ vector.

Define two new vectors
$$\eqalign{
z &= x-y \quad\implies dz = dx\cr
f &= z\otimes z \cr
}$$
Then use the Kronecker expansion to calculate the differential and gradient of $f$.
$$\eqalign{
df &= z\otimes dz + dz\otimes z = (z\otimes I + I\otimes z)\,dx \cr
G=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= (z\otimes I + I\otimes z)
 = (x-y)\otimes I + I\otimes(x-y) \cr
}$$
Let $e_k$ denote the $k^{th}$ column of the $I$ matrix and $w={\rm vec}(I)$.

Use these to vectorize the $G$ matrix.
$$\eqalign{
G &= (z\otimes I + I\otimes z), \quad
M = \pmatrix{I\otimes e_1\cr I\otimes e_2\cr\vdots\cr I\otimes e_n} \cr
g &= {\rm vec}(G) = \Big(M + w\otimes I\Big)\,z \cr
}$$
Now find the differential and gradient of the $g$ vector.
$$\eqalign{
dg &= \Big(M + w\otimes I\Big)\,dx \cr
H = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} &= \Big(M + w\otimes I\Big) \cr
}$$
So that's the hessian in matrix form. The true Hessian is a 3rd order tensor.

Comment: I didn't understand something, if X and Y are vectors, how do you make the Kronecker product of a matrix with a vector and get a vector as a result?

Comment: @dtn Every instance where I have the Kronecker product of a matrix and a vector, it is then multiplied by a vector on the RHS  to produce the vector on the LHS of the equation.