# Derivative of Kronecker Product by vector

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

I'm struggling with the following problem. It is necessary to find the derivative expression with respect to the vector $u$:

$r(u,v)=[(u-v)(u-v)^T]\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}=[(u-v)\otimes (u-v)]\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$

If we use the results from the topic
[Derivative of Kronecker product of vector with itself](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3112634/derivative-of-kronecker-product-of-vector-with-itself), we get:

$\frac{dr}{du}=[(\big(I\otimes(v-u)\big) + \big((v-u) \otimes I\big))]\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$

When I try to figure out the bracketed expression using Mathematica, I get an error.
As far as I understand, something is wrong in the original formula, because the summed arrays have different dimensions.

I need help from more experienced professionals.
I would be glad and grateful for help.

```
Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

u = {a, b, c};

v = {x, y, z};

KroneckerProduct[u - v, u - v] // MatrixForm;

(KroneckerProduct[DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1, 1}], v - u] + 
   TensorProduct[v - u, DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1, 1}]]) // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\v{\operatorname{vec}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\p{{\partial}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$There's no need for Kronecker products, just define the vector
$$\eqalign{
w &= u-v \qquad\qquad\quad \\
dw &= du \\ 
}$$
Write the function in terms of this new variable
$$r = ww^T\o = w\o^Tw \quad $$
Then calculate the differential and its gradient
$$\eqalign{
dr &= dw\;\o^Tw + w\o^T\,dw \\
 &= \Big(\!\left(\o^Tw\right)I+ w\o^T\Big)\,dw \\
 &= \Big(\!\left(\o^Tw\right)I+ w\o^T\Big)\,du \\
\grad{r}{u} &= \left(\o^Tw\right)I+ w\o^T \\
\\
}$$

---

If instead, you really did want the gradient of the scalar function
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= (w\otimes w)^T\o \\
}$$
Then let $J$ denote the *all-ones* matrix
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= (w\otimes w)^T\v(J) \\
  &= \v(w^TJw) \\
  &= w^TJw \\
\grad{\phi}{w} &= 2Jw \;\doteq\; \grad{\phi}{u} \\
}$$

Comment: https://ibb.co/jM4mCxW

Comment: That's correct. You should try to use MathJax. The [site tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) is really good. Also, you can hover over any expression in any post and right-click  "Show Math As..." $\to$ "TeX Commands" to learn a new TeX expressions that catch your eye.

Comment: Thank you! Greg, then let me ask you one more question. A derivative with respect to a vector can be represented in the following form? $\frac{d}{du}(u-v)(u-v)^T=\boldsymbol{1}(u-v)^T+(u-v)\boldsymbol{1}^T$. I tried to apply your calculations for another expression and this is what I got. https://ibb.co/P4TJVs4

Comment: I will try to master MatрJax, just now I don't have much time to write, so I decided to provide the calculation from Mathcad.

Comment: and my result, by the way, is quite similar to what is written in the wiki (please, see vector-by-vector) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Derivatives_with_vectors

Comment: it is likely that I mis-defined the matrix for such a case, i.e. incorrectly adapted your calculations

Comment: The gradient of a matrix wrt a vector (or a vector wrt a matrix) is a third-order _tensor_. Likewise a matrix-by-matrix gradient is a fourth-order tensor. In general, if you ever find yourself trying to calculate such higher-order tensors, you are probably taking the wrong approach to your problem. Most likely, you are trying to applying the chain rule, which is very problematic in matrix calculus.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4199834/extremely-complex-vector-matrix-expression-and-its-differentiation-by-vector 

@greg, please see this topic, is it possible to express the operation of differentiating a matrix with respect to a vector using a single formula?